# Quiero ver una lista creada en un excel desde otro con MACRO

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Existen dos Excel

1. Excel1 que tiene una lista las personas y sus comunas
2. Excel2 que contiene información y un listado de todas las comunas (este Excel no fue creado por mi)

A Excel1 le agrego N personas y me gustaría ver (referenciar) la lista de comunas que se creo en el excel2, para seleccionar.

Luego de seleccionar las comunas en exel1, crear N Excel 2 con la información almacenada en exel1

E buscado diferentes formas de hacerlo, y se que es posible crear una lista en el excel1 con los datos del excel2, pero excel2 no fue creado por mi y ocultaron los datos. Por eso pregunto si se puede referenciar.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español. Posiblemente sí se pueda referenciar pero esto no es un sitio de pedidos a la carta. Por favor, pon el código que has intentado, dónde estás atascado y qué errores obtienes. Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores.

Comment: Si los datos Excel2 te están ocultados, debe haber una razón, y es posible que buscar por estos datos no este posible. Lo lógico sería preguntar a las personas que proporcionan el Excel2 ¿cómo se puede solucionar tu problema?